# How are the FTP, SMTP, SSH ports used?

Tags: ssh, ftp, smtp, ports

I know these are three questions, but I put them together because I think one connects with the other.

I understand that when you want to send an email it's done using the SMTP protocol. Now port 25 is called SMTP for that matter

1. My question is how do these to things work together? For example if you go to Gmail (port 443 for HTTPS) and you send an email using the SMTP, is this port 25 being used somehow? Meaning you go to Gmail (443) and then connects to port (25)?
2. Maybe I got this wrong, but ports are used both as if I am the sender (e.g: I want to make an ssh connection to another PC, so I would send this connection through my port 22 to the others PC port 22), or ports are only for receiving said information, that's to say port 21 receives FTP info but doesn't necessarily transfer files through that port?
3. In the same sense, how is port 21 (FTP) used? Every time there's a process that uses FTP, this and only this port is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now port 25 is called stmp for that matter

No, port 25 is not called SMTP. Port 25 is just a port. SMTP is a protocol.

SMTP usually runs on port 25 on the server. You can use any other port if both the server and client are configured to use it. But we've all agreed that 25 is the default server port for convenience.

The client is actually using a randomly selected *ephemeral* port. That's because it's not necessary to use a known port number on client. It's the client that's connecting to the server - it's enough for client to know server's port, then it can tell the server which port on the client it should talk to.

This approach has two advantages:

1. You can make client connections if the port 25 is already taken by a server.
2. You can make multiple client connections simultaneously.

> [1.] For example if you go to gmail(port 443 for https) and you send an email using the stmp, is this port 25 being used somehow?

If you're using Gmail through its HTTPS web interface in a browser, then you're connecting to it on port 443 only. You're only talking with some HTTP(S) servers. You don't send an email - you instruct the server to do it in your name. The server may be internally making a SMTP connection to the outgoing mail server, but we don't know that. Maybe they're using a different approach.

> [2.] maybe I got this wrong, but ports are used both as if I am the sender(e.g: I want to make an ssh connection to another pc, so I would send this connection through my port 22 to the others pc port 22), or ports are only for receiving said information, that's to say port 21 receives ftp info but doesn't necessarily transfer files through that port?

Ports are bidirectional. You can use then both for sending and receiving (and client's sending is server's receiving). What is being sent and how is determined by the protocol. I won't go into details about the FTP example because 1) I want to keep this answer focused on the networking part and 2) while FTP's passive mode is rather simple, there's also the active mode which I'm not familiar with.

> [3.] in the same sense, how is port 21(ftp) used? every time there's a process that uses ftp, this and only this port is used?

In passive mode it works like the SMTP example I've explained at the beginning. Server opens a known port (typically 21) and listens for connections. Client opens a randomly selected ephemeral port and tries to connect to the server. A bidirectional TCP connection is established and communication follows according to the FTP protocol.

Again, the active mode is a bit more complicated and I'm not familiar with it enough to explain it.

Protocols that run over UDP (rather than TCP) are similar, except no connection is established. UDP is just shouting at the other computer without any verification if the message ever arrives.

Comment: +1 – Thought, the passive FTP mode is not as simple as you describe. There is still an additional data connection on another port. So it's as complicated as the active mode. But I agree that this is too much for one question, which is broad enough already.